# Laravel 10: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, composer

Hola tengo un problema a la hora de querer instalar  en mi proyecto de laravel paquetes utilizando composer, necesito hacer un carrito de compras y a la hora de ejecutar por ejemplo: composer require "darryldecode/cart", obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem 1
- darryldecode/cart 0.0.2 requires illuminate/support 4.2.*@dev -> found illuminate/support[v4.2.1, ..., v4.2.17] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

```
- darryldecode/cart[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.0, 2.0.0, ..., 2.3.0] require illuminate/support 5.0.*@dev -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.33] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- darryldecode/cart[2.4.0, ..., 2.4.1] require illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.1.41] but these were not loaded, likely because it confle were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- darryldecode/cart 4.0.5 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|6.0.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.4] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- darryldecode/cart 4.0.6 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|6.0.*|6.1.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.1.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- darryldecode/cart[4.0.7, ..., 4.1.1] require illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- darryldecode/cart 4.1.2 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- darryldecode/cart[4.2.0, ..., 4.2.1] require illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- darryldecode/cart 4.2.2 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.5] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires darryldecode/cart * -> satisfiable by darryldecode/cart[0.0.2, 1.0.0, ..., 1.1.0, 2.0.0, ..., 2.4.1, 3.0.0, ..., 3.0.5, 4.0.0, ..., 4.2.2].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require darryldecode/cart:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require darryldecode/cart:^2.1" if you know which you need.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Intenté con otros paquetes de carritos de tienda pero en todos pasa lo mismo bueno de los que he probado, instalé otro paquete que no tiene nada que ver con carrito de comparas y este si se instaló.

Mi archivo composer.json es el siguiente:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^3.9",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
    "laravel/jetstream": "^3.1",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.4",
    "livewire/livewire": "^2.11"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
        "php-http/discovery": true
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

Borré la carpeta composer de mi proyecto y la volví a instalar pero no me funcionó. Por favor si alguien me puede orientar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Esd paquete dice que soporta hasta laravel 9 https://packagist.org/packages/darryldecode/cart . Probablemente con los otros sea lo mismo, laravel 10 es relativamente nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Encontré esta librería para Laravel 10, es similar a la libreria darryldecode:
https://packagist.org/packages/ultrono/laravelshoppingcart-1

Para importarla al proyecto se debería poner el comando: `composer require ultrono/laravelshoppingcart-1`

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

intenta con:

```
composer require "darryldecode/cart:~4.2"
```

Comment: Explica el porque de tu respuesta y como es que resuelve la pregunta, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por [answer] y por [tour] para que comprendas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio, de paso ganas tus primeras medallas.